# Extract Shortened Link with imacros

Tags: extract, imacros

I am new to imacros scripting and I want to extract a shortened link on `gg.gg`. This is my test script:

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 3
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP YES
TAG XPATH="//result-box[@id="short-url"] EXTRACT=TXT
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
PAUSE
```

But it still gives a null result. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try this line:

```
TAG XPATH="//*[@id='short-url']" EXTRACT=TXT
```